# How could I use a View node in Android XML layout file?

Tags: android, xml, android-view, android-xml

In Android Studio, I've seen a `<View />` node and this has all of Widget's attributes. I'm curious, what's this node and how could I use it?

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/material_cyan_200"
 />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- This class represents the basic building block for user interface
  components.
- A View occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is
  responsible for drawing and event handling.
- Views are used for Drawing Shapes like Circles,Rectangles,Ovals etc . Just Use View with
  background and apply a Shape using Custom Drawable.
- Even Views can be
  Used a Lines,Place Holders etc

Let me illustrate as per your Example,you have a View Tag as in

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/material_cyan_200"
 />
```

Which will draw an Horizontal line of Color `grey`,
if suppose you need to make it `invisible` or some other action,u can do it in `.java` file as in

```
View v=findViewById(R.id.myview);
v.setVisible(View.GONE); //will remove View from your UI
```

Comment: Nailed it. That piece of code is just supposed to be a line of cyan color separating two different sections or other views most likely

Comment: Oh , you meant this tag unable to use findViewByid in java code and this tag only be use at XML files. Yeah?

Comment: No,you can use it in Java and refer it intoView element by findViewByID

Comment: ive Updated snwer with Example :)

Answer (score 1):

An excellent general explanation has been already done by rajan ks.

If you want to know instant usage meaning of the code, I think it would be a thin horizontal border line which colored with `@color/material_cyan_200`.